# what is the meaning of flag in findall

Tags: python-3.x, python-re, findall

The findall method in python re library has the following signature:
**re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)**
Surprisingly the description below it on the python docs doesn't explain what is the meaning of the third
a parameter called `flag` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1):

Simply search the site for "flag" in your browser:

[image: flags searched in browser]

and scroll down to where the hits in the sidebar concentrate.

You'll find them f.e. documented in the inline flags for patterns:

> [**(?aiLmsux)**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=flags#index-15)
> (One or more letters from the set 'a', 'i', 'L', 'm', 's',
> 'u', 'x'.) The group matches the empty string; the letters set the
> corresponding flags: **re.A** (ASCII-only matching), **re.I** (ignore case),
> **re.L** (locale dependent), **re.M** (multi-line), **re.S** (dot matches all),
> **re.U** (Unicode matching), and **re.X** (verbose), for the entire regular
> expression. **(The flags are described in Module Contents.)** This is
> useful if you wish to include the flags as part of the regular
> expression, instead of passing a flag argument to the re.compile()
> function. Flags should be used first in the expression string.

which relegates you to

> [**Module Contents**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=flags#module-contents)
> The module defines several functions, constants, and
> an exception. Some of the functions are simplified versions of the
> full featured methods for compiled regular expressions. Most
> non-trivial applications always use the compiled form.
>
> Changed in version 3.6: **Flag constants are now instances of RegexFlag,
> which is a subclass of enum.IntFlag.**

> **re.compile(pattern, flags=0)**
> Compile a regular expression pattern into a regular expression object, which can be used for matching using its match(), search() and other methods, described below.

which includes

> The expression’s behaviour can be modified by specifying a flags value. Values can be any of the following variables, combined using bitwise OR (the | operator).

followed by all the flags there are...